# If statment Float isn't swapping value and keeps looping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a matrix3x3 script which i've made a Translation and rotation script from and I have a 2D mesh object that I render in the scene and  I am trying to bounce between two points.

Right being 10 and left being -10

When the object hits the point, I want it to change direction and rotation (translation and angle)

When I run my code the object moves to the right first (10) and then reaches the point and starts to jitter... Like it keeps fighting with both values and won't change direction or angle back towards -10

FYI: the UpdateMesh is for rendering the mesh.vertices and colors for the object in the scene

I have put it in it's own method (instead of just putting it in Update) and have tried fiddling with the values but I still run into the same problem...

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction please (I have a feeling it's something to do with my coding sequence but im not sure...)

```
void RotateAndTranslate()
{
    UpdateMesh();

    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
    //angle += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    //offset2 += 1 * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    offsetpos = offset2;

    if (offset2 <= 10)
    {

        offset2 += 1 * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        angle -= rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
    else if (offset2 >= -10)
    {
        offset2 += -1 * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        angle += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }




    //Get The transformation matrix
    Matrix3x3 T = Transform.Translate(offsetpos, 0);
    Matrix3x3 R = Transform.Rotate(angle);
    //Matrix3x3 T2 = Transform.Translate(-offset.x, -offset.y);
    Matrix3x3 T2 = Transform.Translate(-offset.x, -offset.y);
    Matrix3x3 M = T * R;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        vertices[i] = M.MultiplyPoint(vertices[i]);
    }

    mesh.vertices = vertices;

}

public void Update()
{
    RotateAndTranslate();

}
```

Comment: Think about your `if`s. What does the first one mean? What happens when the value goes down from 10 again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your

```
if (offset2 <= 10)
{
    offset2 += 1 * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    angle -= rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else if (offset2 >= -10)
{
    offset2 += -1 * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    angle += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

What happens here? Lets say you start with `0`.

1. The first block is executed since `0 <= 10` is `true`.
2. At some point you reach a value `10+x` or higher.
3. Now the second block is executed since `10+x <= 10` is `false` but `10+x >= -10` is `true`. So in this frame you reduce the `offset2` again
4. so in the next few frames it will pretty quick again reach a value `<= 10`.

→ And so it starts to jitter around the value `10` since every few frames or maybe even every frame you alternate the direction.

---

A solution for this would be a simple `bool` flag:

```
private bool isGoingRight;

...

int offsetSign = isGoingRight ? 1 : -1;
int angleSign = isGoingRight ? -1 : 1;

if (isGoingRight && offset2 >= 10)
{
    isGoingRight = false;
}
else if (!isGoingRight && offset2 <= -10)
{
    isGoingRight = true;
}

offset2 += offsetSign * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
angle += angleSign * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

The difference: This now only inverts the direction **once** if the according limit is reached.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it a lot easier + my brain can actually understand that,  appreciate it :)